# Distinct column values within categories

Tags: python, unique, distinct

I have following dataframe:

| Category | Product |
| --- | --- |
| 63 | Z |
| 63 | Z |
| 63 | B |
| 63 | C |
| 83 | B |
| 83 | P |
| 84 | B |
| 84 | C |
| 84 | F |
| 85 | B |
| 85 | C |
| 85 | T |
| 85 | X |
| 85 | X |
| 85 | B |

I want to get products, which are unique (distinct) within (4) categories. They can be multiple rows within the same category with the same product, but as soon as the product is present in different category I do not want him to show on new dataframe. I want to drop repetitive rows, unless they are in the same category and not in the others.

OUTPUT:

| Category | Product |
| --- | --- |
| 63 | Z |
| 63 | Z |
| 83 | P |
| 84 | F |
| 85 | T |
| 85 | X |
| 85 | X |

I was trying to count unique values like this, but unsucessfuly:

```
new_df=df.drop_duplicates(['Category','Product'])[['Category','Product']]
```

I wanted also to display the most common product for the category, but those graphs have duplications within categories unfortunetly (eg. 63 category)

```
new_df = df[df['Category'] == 63].copy()
new_df['Product'].value_counts()[:10].plot(kind='barh')
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have added my code @ExtraFishness

Answer (score 0):

I would count the number of (distinct) categories for each product, and remove those that have more than 1. Then a join of the initial dataframe with this new one should do the job

```py
df_calc = df.groupBy(df.Product).agg(countDistinct(df.Category)).alias('nb_cat').filter(df.nb_cat == 1)
new_df = df.join(df_calc, on='Product')
```

The join will be a cross join but `df_calc` should have only one row per product.

Comment: Thanks for respond! I bump into SyntaxError: 'expression cannot contain assignment, perhaps you meant "=="?'. After adding '==' I got 'AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'groupBy''

Comment: Yes my mistake, sorry the right syntax is `==`, I edited my post. Do you still have the issue if you change?

Comment: After changing from "groupBy' to groupby I have "NameError: name 'countDistinct' is not defined". Before the change it was "AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'groupBy'"

Comment: You might need to import related module (`from pyspark.sql import functions as F`) then use `F.countDistinct()`

Comment: OK, I think I know what's wrong: I thought you were using pyspark, but you use pandas, don't you? In this case, countDistinct does not exist and you might use [`nunique()` method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nunique.html). I will not edit my post as I'm not familiar with pandas syntax